# Where to find the Data for ElasticSeach

Tags: json, database, elasticsearch, dataset

I wanted some text data that might look like emails or letters which i can use while experimenting the API in elasticsearch.
But I haven't been able to find any yet. Can anyone suggest me some sources where one can find the data?
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the next URL in the browser:
localhost:9200/_search

Do you see data?

(If the elasticsearch is in server and you are in remote computer replace the localhist with your IP)

Comment: I am looking for some external data which i can store in my database. I want a dataset which have some text in English language. It may be any thing but i want it to be in JSON format.
Still thanks that you pondered over the question

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [enron dataset](https://github.com/ycombinator/es-enron) as a nice start...

Comment: Thanks for the dataset. It is for sure a good place to start.